# date in spanish webform component coming out in day month year , need month day year

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

My webform in english shows  the date component as month day year.
but when I translate it to spanish it shows the date as day month year.  How can I modify the format for dates when in different languages?

FOUND THE ANSWER: go to /admin/config/regional/date-time/locale/es/edit and change the date format to month first for the long, short and medium dates

Comment: "modify the format for dates when in different languages" Actually, isn't that what is already happening? The date format becomes localized? That would seem to be the correct behavior. Not sure how webform does the formatting of dates though, where exactly do you see this date? Is it a field you've added?

Comment: Great that you found an answer, but please post it as an answer below (and accept it when you can), or this question will remain in an unanswered state.

Comment: it wont let me answer my own question since I dont have enough points!

Comment: I see, I took the liberty of posting the answer for you then. :) Please consider accepting it so we can remove it from the unanswered queue. :) (Yes, this would give me undeserved reputation, but I hope we can agree to call it "drop in a pond")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on behalf of Diana that can't do it due to reputation limits.

Go to `/admin/config/regional/date-time/locale/es/edit` and change the date format to month first for the long, short and medium dates.